# Divide two columns into group by function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, divide

If I have the below select query:

```
select col1, col2, col3, sum(value1) as col4, col5
from table1
group by col1, col2, col3, col5
```

How to add col6 = col4/col5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the alias in the `SELECT` clause. So you have to repeat `sum(value1)`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
       sum(value1) as col4, 
       col5, 
       sum(value1) / col5 as col6
from table1
group by col1, col2, col3, col5
```

Comment: @4est No, this field is calculated using aggregated fields (col5) and non-aggregated fields (value1) that appear in aggregation functions (sum).

Answer (score 1):

Do the `GROUP BY` in a derived table:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col4/col5 as col6 
from
(
    select col1, col2, col3, sum(value1) as col4, col5
    from table1
    group by col1, col2, col3, col5
) dt
```

Comment: @JamieD77, thank you for the correction!  Have a nice weekend! (I'm so happy it's finally Friday. I need to rest.)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform operations in the select statement. However, you cannot use the aliases of the SQL statement within it. So you need to do the calculation for col4 again. Just add `sum(value1)/col5 as col6`.

```
select col1, col2, col3, sum(value1) as col4, col5, sum(value1)/col5 as col6
from table1
group by col1, col2, col3, col5
```